# How can I add edges to my graph in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, graph, jgrapht

I use jgrapht library in Java to create some graphs. I want to iterate through the existing vertices(that I have created in a previous state of the program) and add the corresponding edges depending on some criteria(if statements). As it seems to me the only way to add edges is:

```
 DefaultWeightedEdge e1 = exampleGraph.addEdge("1", "2");           
 exampleGraph.setEdgeWeight(e1, 20.0);
```

From my point of view, this won't work in a for loop because it will always refer and change the same object. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you store those vertices?

Comment: Vertices are added to the graph in the same way with the commands: exampleGraph.addVertex("1");
exampleGraph.addVertex("2"); Is that what you ask?

Comment: Do you know how to store multiple values in arrays?

Comment: Yes, of course. Maybe my mind is stuck right now. How would that happen. Can you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for loop
{
    exampleGraph.setEdgeWeight(exampleGraph.addEdge(x, y), w);
}
```

Did you try something like this?

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner in object-oriented programming as you can see.